# Any way to get the line of a Match object?

Tags: python, regex

I'm a beginner in programming, using python, and I'm trying to read a text file with multiple lines and apply a regex to check every match, the problem is, I need to know in which line in the file the match starts.

```
file = open(data)
data = file.read()
file.close()

result = re.finditer(r'--(\d+)\t+.+(?:\n--\1\t+.+)*', data)
for match in result:
    ...
```

Since I read the whole file at the beginning, I'm using finditer to find all the matches in the content. Is there a way I can tell at what line does the each match start? I can't seem to find any in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match objects have [`Match.start()` and `Match.end()` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) that give you the offsets for the start and end of a match into the entire string.  Count the number of `\n` line separators before that point to translate these into a line number.

The following function counts the number of newlines preceding the matched position, adding 1 to number lines starting at 1 rather than at 0:

```
def line_for_match(m):
    return m.string.count("\n", 0, m.start()) + 1
```

If your matches can span multiple lines, you may want to use `m.end()` in there and count the number of newlines matched between start and end by counting `\n` characters in `m[0]`.

The function makes use of the extra arguments to the [`str.count()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to limit counting to the part of the input string (referenced via [`Match.string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.string)); they are the start and end positions in the string, respectively.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> def line_for_match(m):
...     return m.string.count("\n", 0, m.start()) + 1
...
>>> data = "foosball\nbartender\nbazar\n" * 3
>>> pattern = r"(?:foo|bar)"
>>> print(data)
foosball
bartender
bazar
foosball
bartender
bazar
foosball
bartender
bazar

>>> for m in re.finditer(pattern, data):
...     print(f"{line_for_match(m)}: {m[0]}")
...
1: foo
2: bar
4: foo
5: bar
7: foo
8: bar
```